# Problems with Internal Styles in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates

Kee-doke.

So I have internal style problems. With Wordpress. After many frustrating hours trying to figure out how to change styles on several different items, I discovered that the main html file had a ton of internal style sheets. They were overriding my styles that I input in the style.css file of my Wordpress theme.

The styles are inside the `<head>` of the web page. I need to know where I can go to edit these internal styles. That is, what template file holds them?

There is a lot of code, but here is the relevant stuff. The styles are way down at the bottom. I removed the actual styles. I just need to find out how to edit them. Obviously they have to be in a Wordpress php file. But which one?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Trailogy | Find the Trail. Hit the Trail</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://localhost/wordpress/xmlrpc.php" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp- content/uploads/2014/10/LogoThumbFav.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/LogoThumbFav.png" /><link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Trailogy &raquo; Feed" href="http://localhost/wordpress/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Trailogy &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://localhost/wordpress/comments/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nirvanas-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nirvana/style.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nirvana/js/frontend.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nirvana/js/nivo-slider.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/wordpress/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.0" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  jquery stuff for a slider.
</script>
<style type="text/css"> /*Hundreds of lines of css*/</style>
<style type="text/css">/* Nirvana Custom CSS */</style>'
```

And by the way STYLE.CSS ISN'T OVERRIDING THESE INTERNAL STYLES! That's the problem.

EDIT: Why me? Yeah, so after spending a whole day trying to figure this out, my associate up and says, "Dude, you can just add `!important` to the end of your styles and they'll override everything." So I created a style override css sheet. Talk about the solution staring me in the face!

Comment: How in the world are we supposed to know this, without seeing source code? Please include code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the stylesheet you are looking for:

> /wordpress/wp-content/themes/nirvana/style.css?ver=4.0